# How to retrieve data from a database as INT in SQL/PHP?

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to create an imaginary ATM for a schoolproject but I'm stuck on something.
Everything works fine but I can take more money from my account than I have.
For example:
    *I have 1300 euro's in the database and I input 1400 euro's my system happily updates my balance from 1300 to -100.*
 And that's exactly what I don't want to happen. My code right no looks like this:

```
if (( /* i have no clue what comes here */ -$bedrag)>0)   // This should become something like: IF "value from database" > "amount"   (bedrag=amount btw)
                {
                echo "Het pinnen is gelukt!"; 
                $pinnen= "UPDATE rekeningen SET Saldo= Saldo - '$bedrag' WHERE Rekeningnr ='$nummer'";
                mysql_query($pinnen);
                }
```

Comment: So your question is how to avoid negative numbers? What should happen instead - should the operation be rejected completely, or the amount set to 0?

Comment: Do you have a query that's not working, or are you actually asking how to query a value from the database? If it's the latter, I can only recommend that you RTFM: http://www.php.net/manual/en/set.mysqlinfo.php, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to *add*, not subtract the amount in your `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE rekeningen SET Saldo= Saldo + '$bedrag' WHERE Rekeningnr ='$nummer'
                                   ^
```

You can then use a negative value for withdrawals.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle this application-side. Query for the required information on page load, and save the values in sessionStorage:

```
window.onload = function() {
    sessionStorage.saldoval = "<?php $return['Saldo'] ?>";
}
```

Then validate it with Javascript before submitting.

```
var saldo = document.getElementById('SaldoInput');

if(saldo.value > sessionStorage.saldoval){
    // do something to tell the user they're naughty
    return false;
}
```

You shouldn't rely on the database to perform this kind of validation.

Comment: Seriously?  You recommend validating financial transactions (even fake ones) in javascript?  Javascript validation is there for making a better user experience, not for real validation.

Comment: this isn't **real** validation, this is simple preventative steps. avoiding unnecessary calls to the DB like this is good practice. but in fairness, using the data attributes probably wasn't the best idea, sessionStorage would be much better.

Comment: Avoiding unnecessary calls to the DB is a good thing.  That's not an unnecessary call to the DB.  What if the balance changes between page loads?  Or the user has multiple sessions?

Comment: then i guess we would use your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a variable, let's say, `$current_balance`, that stores the balance of the account before the operation, you could go like this:

```
if ($bedrag > $current_balance) {
 echo "You don't have enough money, sir!";
}
else {
 echo "Het pinnen is gelukt!"; 
 $pinnen= "UPDATE rekeningen SET Saldo= Saldo - '$bedrag' WHERE Rekeningnr ='$nummer'";
 mysql_query($pinnen);
}
```

Besides, it would be a good idea to set a check constraint on the `Saldo` field in your table to avoid negative values. Just saying.